# How can I effectively design a messaging system with this present schema design?

Tags: postgresql, data-modeling

I am setting up the database schema for a messaging application. I have a messages table that stores the subject, body,creator(id of the person that sent the message), status(sent, draft, unread) messages and other info then I also have a sent table to keep track of the messageid (id of the message from the messages table) and senderid (id of the sender from user table) and also inbox table that keeps track of the messageid and receiverid(id of the receiver from user table). I want to achieve the following:

- Does it make sense that each time I insert into messages table(post a message), I programmatically set the status as 'sent' for the sender and 'unread' for the receiver?
- Considering the frontend, does it make sense that every message in the inbox is unread by default so when it is clicked, it becomes read?
- How about setting another status in inbox table which will be 'unread' by default as I insert into inbox table for the receiver and 'sent' in the messages table for the receiver?
- How can I effectively keep track of the parentmessageid and use it to start a thread as a reply to an initial message?

This is how the messages table looks now

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  subject CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
  message CHARACTER VARYING(500) NOT NULL,
  parentmessageid INTEGER NULL,
  creator INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (parentmessageid) references messages (id) on delete CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (creator) references users (id) on DELETE CASCADE,
  status CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
  createdon TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
)`;
```

The inbox table:

```
CREATE TABLE inbox (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  messageid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  receiverid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (messageid) REFERENCES messages (id) on DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (receiverid) REFERENCES users (id) on DELETE CASCADE,
  createdon TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
)`;
```

The sent table:

```
CREATE TABLE sent (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  messageid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  senderid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (messageid) REFERENCES messages (id) on DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (senderid) REFERENCES users (id) on DELETE CASCADE,
  createdon TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
)`;
```

N.B: I have seen some answers here on stackoverflow regarding similar questions but I am just curious as to how this my present design would work.

I don't think this question needs to be put on hold. StackOverflow is a community of professionals and my question was asked to see other and better ways I can achieve the same goal. The opinions are appreciated because we get to learn from anyone that answers the question. As it stands, only one person has answered the question so how do we get to learn then?

Comment: *"Does it make sense that each time I insert into messages table(post a message), I programmatically set the status as 'sent' for the sender"* No. What about saving draft? Sending being still in progress ?

Comment: Status should be in another table. Then you will easily query the messages having this or that status instead of risking a typo and multiplying the disk space occupied by a repeated information

Comment: I upvote for the efforts you put in your question, but I voted to close, since this is opinion based and too broad

Comment: @Cid makes sense but how can a status of draft be achieved from the backend?

Comment: This is even broader :D add a button that saves the message ?

Comment: @Cid thanks. I undestand what you have said but I won't mind other opinions

Comment: Can a user send many times the same message ? (by same message, I mean messages with the same id)

Comment: Another question : is the creator of a message **always** the sender, and is the sender **always** the creator ?

Comment: @Cid I never even thought of that but I think each message should carry a new id by that, each row will be different.

Comment: @Cid Yes with this present implementation.

Comment: There is duplication of informations then, `senderid` of table `sent` can be retrieved in `creator` of table `messages`

Comment: For same message, I meant this : *"User A write a message to User B. Few moments later, User A watch his Sent "folder" and want to send that message to User C"* Is that possible ?

Comment: @Cid you are right to have spotted that but ``creator``` can always be removed from ```messages``` table.

Comment: Yes, it's up to you, that's a 1,1 - 1,1 relation, the FK can be in any of the tables

Comment: @Cid that's another twist to the whole flow because I never thought of that but I think it should register as a new message for _User B_ and _User C_ hence new ids

Comment: Not necessary. In fact, you shouldn't duplicate the messages if they are the same.

Comment: Can a user receive twice or more the same message? (need to go, I couldn't answer before a while)

Comment: @Cid these are cases I never honestly considered...

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on what you want to achieve, but your data model seems too complicated to me.

I would simply have a `messages` and a `users` table. Each message has a sender and a recipient (linked by foreign key), a `sender_status` (draft/sent/...) and a `recipient_status` (unread/read/deleted).

The inbox and outbox need not be tables, they are determined by querying the `messages` table.

Comment: This is another way of looking at it. Thumbs up